# 404 Not Found - When I try to run Orcale Apex Application after installation

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-ords, oracle-apex-20.2

I just installed oracle apex 20.2 and oracle data service (ords 20.3).

I am trying to run an application created in Apex but Ords gives me a 404 error yet I believe I have followed the documentation and the configuration of ords.

The error image:

[image]

Comment: Try Java -jar ords.war validate

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when I imported an application.
Try this: in application properties untick "Friendly URLs" and run it again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked for me on Apex 21.1